# Firebase - How to validate user credentials from the server?

Tags: api, firebase, firebase-authentication

In a project we are working on we need to validate user credentials on our system for a 3rd party partner with RESTful API.

This all was very simple when we used our own system and DB, However we are moving to Firebase Auth now.

We need the 3rd party to send email & password to our server (via API..) and the server to check credentials validation or login to Firebase.

Is it even possible with Firebase?

We know (actually we asked the Firebase team and they told us) about the Admin SDK and Custom Token - but we still can't find the way to utilize it for our need.

Comment: Is the email and password to be managed by Firebase Auth? Or is this an existing Auth system that needs to be used with other Firebase services?

Comment: We wanted to switch to full Firebase solution with Firebase Auth.